# What does this mean (handwriting)

Tags: translation, characters

Can you all help me to translate this character. It was written on machine that was delivered to me, and it is malfunctioning, i thought this might give me a clue.[image]

Comment: This might be upside down)

Answer (score 1):

一楼 yīlóu
1st floor

Not much help as far as fixing it goes!

Comment: Thanks for prompt response)